# French notational differences

Tags: notation, mathematical-french

I wish to read some French probability / measure theory papers. I do not wish to be caught out with different notations. For example if "compact" in French has a weaker meaning than in English literature.

So aside from the difference in open interval notation, ie. ]a,b[ instead of (a,b), are there any other major differences in assumed definitions/notations between the English/American literature?

Thanks, Tom

Comment: No major differences.

Comment: a.e. becomes p.p.

Comment: This [translation table](http://www.math.unicaen.fr/~reyssat/dico/dicofa.html) (and the converse one) may help. You should take care to inequalities : 'positif (ou nul)' or 'supérieur (ou égal)' in french allows equality so that 'positif (ou nul)' (see the tables) should be translated by 'nonnegative', 'strictement positif' corresponding to the english 'positive'.

Comment: Though it's not *strictly* a language issue, my impression is that the use of "compact" to mean "compact Hausdorff" is more common in the French literature than elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you everyone for answering. Gerry, thank you for that. Raymond, that table will be pretty useful for me, thanks. Andreas, I thought it would be something like that, thanks.