# Is a locally compact subgroup of a locally compact group closed?

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, locally-compact-groups

I encountered the following exercise in Terry's Tao book on Hilbert's fifth problem:

> Let $G$ be a locally compact group and let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Show that $H$ is closed if and only if $H$ is locally compact.

The direction assuming that $H$ is closed I managed to prove. However I have been struggling to prove the other direction since it is not explicitly given that $G$ is Hausdorff. I've been told that the exercise is not true without assuming Hausdorff, but I wanted to be sure whether this is indeed the case.

Is the assumption of Hausdorff implict and necessary, or is the statement true in the non-Hausdorff case as well?

Comment: Many authors *require* topological groups to be Hausdorff. Tao doesn't?

Comment: Without the Hausdorff condition, there is also some ambiguity about what *local compactness* could mean. I would typically define it to be: given any point $x \in X$ and any neighborhood $U$ of $x$ in $X$, there is a compact neighborhood $V$ of $x$ in $X$ with $V \subseteq U$ (*neighborhood* here just means a subset of $X$ containing $x$ in its interior). But some authors (e.g., Munkres) just require that each $x$ possesses some compact neighborhood. What is Tao's definition?

Comment: In a later exercise he discusses the closure of $\{ 1_G \}$, and asks to show that it is a normal compact subgroup if the original group is locally compact, which suggests that we're not generally assuming topological groups to be Hausdorff.

Comment: I also didn't find a definition in the book for locally compact, but I think the definition is that of Munkres.

Comment: Many authors when they define compact (and locally compact) spaces assume Hausdorff. I suspect that Tao does the same. See this discussion: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1359191/necessity-of-being-hausdorff-in-the-definition-of-compactness

Comment: Indeed in the context of (locally) compact groups this convention that it's Hausdorff is very frequent (more than for arbitrary compact spaces). I should also recall that for non-Hausdorff spaces, while the notion of "compact" is clear-cut, the notion of "locally compact" is highly ambiguous, since many obviously equivalent definitions (in Hausdorff setting) then fail to be equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without Hausdorff it is not true. Take any locally compact non-Hausdorff group $G$. Then $H = \{ 1_G \}$ is locally compact and non-closed.

Concrete example: Any nontrivial group $G$ with the trivial topology. This is compact and locally compact, independent from the definition of local compactness (see the discussion in Stephen's comment).